# Android BuildConfig class values are null

Tags: java, android, gradle

In my app I need to fetch the app version code and name so I was using below statement.

```
 obj.setCurrentVersion("APP " + 
 String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME));
```

It was working fine and returns correct result.
But now it's return empty string once i checked BuildConfig class all the values are empty.

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    public static final java.lang.String APPLICATION_ID = "androidx.multidex";
    public static final java.lang.String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
    public static final java.lang.String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = -1;
    public static final java.lang.String VERSION_NAME = "";

    public BuildConfig() { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Build_gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
         
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.application"
        minSdkVersion 21 //21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 16 //15
        versionName "2.0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Why is that happening and how to fix it?

Comment: post `build.gradle` file

Comment: @KishoreJethava added

Comment: You are searching in wrong `BuildConfig`. the `applicationId "com.app.application"` of build.gradle is not same in `BuildConfig` applicationId.

Comment: @KishoreJethava Yeah right i didn't notice that. How to solve it? shall I change the application id value in BuildConfig manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You import wrong BuildConfig file**

Remove your BuildConfig import & re-import your app module BuildConfig